# PostgreSQL - relation [table] does not exist

Tags: postgresql

everyone.

I am not the first one who asked this questions.

I read and tried everything but nothing is working, at least for me

In database, I have two tables 
[image]

First one  'facility' working without any problem.

The second 'questions' generates error

Database query failed: ERROR: relation "questions" does not exist LINE 1: select * from questions ^

I tried use table_scema (it's public and not necessary) but this is not working too.

Database query failed: ERROR: relation "public.questions" does not exist LINE 1: select * from public.questions ^

Database, table, fields everything in low case Adding double quote is not helping too.

Any Ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you querying the db? psql or pgAdmin?

Comment: I tried all field and individual such as group_id, groupe_name, for database access - phpPgAdmin 5.1 and   DataGrip 2016 and inside everything working without problem.

Comment: Can you make sure that your SQL Query window is pointing to the right database?  If you go to the object browser and navigate to the questions table, right click View Data -> View Top 100 Rows  can you see the data then?

Comment: Could there be some spaces or unprintable characters in the table name?

Comment: Hi Julia,  Yes I can view data in phpPgAdmin and in DataGrip.

Comment: Laurenz, On screenshots it's no spaces.

Comment: Additional: Any new test table I created has the same error. I really love PostgreSQL

Comment: The screenshot above (showing list of columns) and the query to questions table -- were they entered in the same query prompt?

Comment: Thank you, Julia, yes. I tried columns name.  I really don't have any idea what happened. I created a couple of test tables using different tools. The tables have one column and simple names like aaa or test and NOTHING. the same error.   More interesting two other old tables in the same database querying with out any problem from the same code

Comment: Thank you every one.  After duplicated database, everything working as should be.